# is there an analytic formula for the position of 1 in an array representing permutations?

Tags: algorithm, permutation

Let's say for example we have a state that has N sites. Each of these sites can hold a 0 or a 1 in them (there is no particle in or there is).

For example for N = 3 the possible states are |0,0,0>; |1,0,0>; |0,1,0>; |0,0,1>; |1,1,0>; |1,0,1>; |0,1,1>; |1,1,1>

For reasons that are irrelevant to this question, these are representations of particle states in physics. More specifically these are permutations of spinless Fermions. As such they are constructed by doing the tensor product between the single states.
For example

|0,1,0> = |0> ⊗ |1> ⊗ |0>  (There is 1 fermion at site number 2. Sites 1 and 3 are empty)

where each state can be represented explicitly as a vector in its own Space.

|0> = (1,0) (a fermion is NOT present in this |k> state) This is also known as the vacuum state

|1> = (0,1) (a fermion IS present in this |k> state)

This allows us to do the product numerically and the output will be the final state vector whose dimension is 2^(N)

So:

|0,1,0> = |0> ⊗ |1> ⊗ |0> = (1,0) ⊗ (0,1) ⊗ (1,0) = (0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) as vector

or

|0,1,1> = |0> ⊗ |1> ⊗ |1> = (1,0) ⊗ (0,1) ⊗ (0,1) = (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0) as vector

The problem is doing all these tensor products can be very time consuming for large number of sites. But it is relevant to see that no matter what the state, the final explicit Vector will be sparse. It will always have a single one "1" at some position and the rest will be guaranteed zeros.

My question now is, is there an analytic expression to know prior where the unique "1" will land so that i can avoid doing the products?

One interesting thing to notice is that by taking the 8 states i enumerated above, for each of them the "1" is simply displaced 1 index downwards in the vector as we permute through the combinations. And the order is pretty obvious. We start by shifting the "1" element along the N positions. Then we keep the first element at 0 and move the 1 along the remaining tail of the abstract state. And we repeat so until our state is achieved.

So here our 8 enumerated states in vectors form are ordered:

```
(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) = |0,0,0>
(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) = |1,0,0>
(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) = |0,1,0>
(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0) = |1,1,0>
(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0) = |0,0,1>
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0) = |1,0,1>
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0) = |0,1,1>
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1) = |1,1,1>
```

One way to see this is, how many permutations are needed by this rule so that ours is achieved? If we know this, we know the unique "1" element will have index = to this number of permutations

This is easy to do for N=3 sites. But for 14 particles this is impossible to do by eye.

Comment: This looks like it's just the binary representation of the index?

Comment: Can you provide some example code for working with these values, how do you represent them? What do you get as an input, what do you expect as an output? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] in your favourite language, then I can write a concrete answer

Comment: You'll lose a lot of people by casting this as a fermion/physics problem and using symbols that won't be familiar to most people here. I suggest recasting the problem as inputs, operations, and outputs. Failing that, at least define what '⊗' is and explain what information value, if any, is conveyed by the '|' and '>' in expressions like '|0,1,0>'

Comment: @Bergi this is VERY barebones
https://github.com/dcthecook/Many_Body_Theory/blob/main/2quantization.ipynb

So how i wanted to work with this is that i want to have a struct for the state for example
|0,1,0> that the user inputs as a string. The create_fermion will return the struct.
The function "create_explicit_fermions" should return an array (vector) that has only one 1 and the rest zeros as put in the post.
There must be a way to get the 1 in the correct index without doing all the tensor products

Comment: @Bergi also the language does not matter i use cython for my ease but i want to understand how to approach this more logically. I was thinking maybe see the state |0,1,0,0,1,0> for example and find in the string where the last 1 is. Then displace the vector 1 depending on how many occupied states came before it. this was unsuccessful but i think it is the correct way approximately

Comment: Basically the index will be `0b010010`. Just take the state as bits of an integer - little endian

Comment: @Bergi i am not sure if i can agree (maybe i misunderstand you) because in our representation a 0 in front your state is actually relevant. For example 0b010010 is 34. But so is 0b10010. And these are fundamentally different vectors. Beginning with their dimensionality

Comment: @Bergi is right. 0b010010 = 18 and is valid only for N=6. 0b10010 = 9 and is valid only for N=5. 0b01001 is also valid for N=5, but the index is again 18. The leftmost bit is the least significant bit, in your representation.

Comment: @MephistophelesFaust You were asking about the index of the `1` value, not about the vector length… The vector length is `2**space_size`.

Comment: @Bergi yes but for example 1010 has a dimension 2**4 . The 1 will be at index 5 out of 0-15 even tho 1010 is binary for 10.  101000 will also have 1 at the same index while it is binary for 40
On the other hand 001 is still binary for 1 but 0⊗1⊗1 gives vector (00001000) which is index 4

Comment: @Bergi i added an answer with code if you are interested. i carried out by hand calculations seems the method works. Cheers <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all commenters especially @Bergi for inspiring the answer.

Unfortunately i am not sure i can fully agree because for example adding 0 in a state such as 10010 -> 10010000 will represent a bigger binary number (bigger index) but doing the explicit tensor products between 1⊗0 and 1⊗0⊗0⊗0 does not change the index

again where 1 is the vector (0,1) and 0 is (1,0). While it does change the overall dimensionality.

With that being said i approached it like this. I take the first state 0 or 1 in the input string corresponding to its own vector. If the state is 0 the final index = 0 and if 1 index = 1. I move right on the string and if the next entry is a 0 state, i simply double the dimensions and leave the index unchanged. However if the next state is a 1, i will double the dimensions and add that to the current index. This represents the shift being done if you tensor product the vector with (0,1). The code is as follows:

create_fermions creates the f_state struct which is simply the binary string (the reason these are ints is because they will be used for direct diagonalization later. in fact they should be doubles but this is not a problem for now). This function is meant to facilitate the entry of a state by the user

The create_explicit_fermion takes the output of the previous function and uses the technique i described above to return a pointer to the explicit vector/array representation. The index of the "1" element seems to be in the correct position.

```
%%cython
cimport cython
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free
from cython cimport sizeof
#import numpy as np
#cimport numpy as np



ctypedef struct f_state:
    int* state
    int size

cdef void free_fermions(f_state fstate) nogil:
    free(fstate.state)


cdef f_state create_fermions(str state, int space_size):
    cdef int* state_array = <int*>malloc(space_size*sizeof(int))
    if state_array is NULL:
        raise MemoryError("Failed to allocate memory for state_array")
    
    for i in range(space_size):
        if state[i] not in ('0', '1'):
            raise ValueError("spinless fermion states can only have 1 occupation or none 0")
        state_array[i] = <int>state[i]-48 #minus 48 because of ascii encoding from str to int. 0 is 48 in ascii. 1 is 49
    cdef f_state fstate
    fstate.state = state_array
    fstate.size = space_size
    return fstate

cdef int* create_explicit_fermions(f_state in_state):
    #start by allocating the vector
    cdef int total_size = 2**in_state.size
    #malloc this to mem
    #....to be completed
    cdef int tmp_dimension
    cdef int index
    if in_state.state[0] == 0:
        index = 0
    elif in_state.state[0] == 1:
        index = 1
    if (in_state.size > 1):
        for i in range(in_state.size):
            tmp_dimension = 2**(i+1)
            if (in_state.state[i+1] == 0):
                index = index
            elif (in_state.state[i+1] == 1):
                index = index + tmp_dimension
    cdef int* result = <int*>malloc(total_size*sizeof(int))
    for i in range(total_size):
        result[i] = 0
    result[index] = 1
    return result

    








#test unit 2

cdef str fermions = "001"
cdef int fsize = 3

cdef f_state fermion_state = create_fermions(fermions, fsize)
for i in range(fsize):
    print(fermion_state.state[i])

print("\nnow the explicit vector\n")
cdef int* fermion_vector = create_explicit_fermions(fermion_state)
for i in range(2**fsize):
    print(fermion_vector[i])
    
free_fermions(fermion_state)
free(fermion_vector)
```

The following test unit gives

```
the state in diract notation
0
0
1

the state in an explicit Fock space vector

0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
```

which is the correct result if you carry out the tensor products by hand

More complicated example for:

fermions = "010010"
fsize = 6

give

```
the state in diract notation
0
1
0
0
1
0

the state in an explicit Fock space vector

0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

at index 18

Thanks to these i can now calculate full matrices for creation-annahilation operators

@Bergi if there is a way to do it like you suggested or more efficiently feel free to provide a code. Thanks for the help